# Get OrderId in Order Confirmation page

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk

I am developing an app for BigCommerce, which i have to inject a [Script](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/store-management/scripts) into Order Confirmation page.

In the script, I want to read the [current order detail](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/storefront/orders/order/ordersbyorderidget), so i try this

```
<script>
 function getOrderDetail(orderId) {
    return fetch("/api/storefront/order/" + orderId, {
      credentials: "include",
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    });
  }
let ORDER_ID=123;
getOrderDetail(ORDER_ID).then(data=>{
// do this ,do that,
})

</script>
```

I don't find any docs related to get current Order_ID, I have inspected the HTML code and tried

```
function getOrderId() {
    const orderIdRegex = /\s+orderId:\s'(\d+)',/;
    return document.body.innerHTML.match(orderIdRegex)[1];
  }
```

I know the code may break if there is a change in UI.

In `Shopify`, there is a global variable `window.Shopify`,

I am wondering if there is a better solution, or something similar to Shopify.

### Update with correct answer

Thanks @MattCoy

```
<script>
 function getOrderDetail(){
    return fetch("/api/storefront/order/{{checkout.order.id}}", {
      credentials: "include",
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    });
  }

 getOrderDetail().then(data=>{
   // do this ,do that,
 })

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a script in the Script Manager, you should have access to all the Stencil theme objects via Handlebars. In this case, try `{{checkout.order.id}}`.

Comment: Hi @Matt, Is there a way to get full `OrderDetail` in ScriptManager at `order_confirmation_page` rather than calling `fetch("/api/storefront/order/" + orderId)` ? Because calling an API will delay my logic a bit.

Comment: @vanduc1102, unfortunately, no. The only other method I could think of would be to set cookies/localStorage variables while on the checkout page, using the Stencil cart object. Though this is a bit hacky.